# Use Repository factory and repository factor design pattern together

Tags: c#, generics, repository, factory

My DbRepository class is the following:

```
public class DbRepository<TEntity, TDbContext> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class, IEntity
    where TDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected readonly TDbContext dbContext;

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="DbRepository{TEntity}" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public DbRepository(TDbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public async Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        ObjectCheck.EntityCheck(entity, $"{nameof(TEntity)} missing.");
        await dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(entity);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return entity;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetAsync(object primaryKey)
    {
        ObjectCheck.PrimaryKeyCheck(primaryKey, $"primaryKey <= 0 in {nameof(IRepository<TEntity>)}");
        return await dbContext.Set<TEntity>().FindAsync(primaryKey);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public virtual IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        return (filter != null ? dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Where(filter) : dbContext.Set<TEntity>());
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public virtual async Task<TEntity> GetSingleAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter)
    {
        return await dbContext.Set<TEntity>().SingleOrDefaultAsync(filter);
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public virtual async Task<TEntity> UpdateAsync(TEntity entity)
    {
        ObjectCheck.EntityCheck(entity, $"{nameof(TEntity)} missing.");
        dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Update(entity);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        return entity;
    }

    /// <inheritdoc/>
    public virtual async Task DeleteAsync(object primaryKey)
    {
        var entityToBeDeleted = await GetAsync(primaryKey);
        ObjectCheck.EntityCheck(entityToBeDeleted, $"{nameof(TEntity)} missing.");

        dbContext.Set<TEntity>().Remove(entityToBeDeleted);
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

}
```

My interface is the following:

```
   public interface IRepository<TEntity>
      where TEntity : class, IEntity
   {
    Task<TEntity> GetAsync(object primaryKey);

    IQueryable<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null);

    Task<TEntity> GetSingleAsync(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter);

    Task<TEntity> AddAsync(TEntity entity);

    Task<TEntity> UpdateAsync(TEntity entity);

    Task DeleteAsync(object primaryKey);
   }
```

How do I register them as scoped in the startup and tell for each class to create repository? Would then I be able to write tests on those repositories?

I have 4 models and I do not want to create repository classes and interfaces for each one of them They are always the same - simple crud operations. Rather I want the factory to create them.

```
public class RepositoryFactory
    {
        public static TRepository GetRepositoryInstance<T, TRepository>()
         where TRepository : IRepository<T>, new()
        {
            return new TRepository();
        }
    }
```

The error I get is The type  must be a reference type in order to use as parameter TEntity in the generic type or method IRepository

Comment: DI is to create your instances. when you wanna create with factory, you would better register factory. In  your case, I would register RepositoryFactory in DI, by converting static method to instance method and in startup:  services.AddSingleton(new RepositoryFactory()); Singleton, because Factory pattern is creational pattern and you use factory to create your repos, not DI. Another way to register is putting factory aside and doing so: services.AddScoped<IRepository<Student>, Repository<Student>(); and do this for all 4 entities. All in all, I don't recommend any of these solutions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It gives you that error because the in the IRepository interface you told the T has to be a class (reference type) and it has to implement the IEntity interface.

In the factory you didn't say none of them.

Probably you have to write something like that:

```
public class RepositoryFactory
{
    public static TRepository GetRepositoryInstance<T, TRepository>()
          where TRepository : IRepository<T>, new()
          where T : class, IEntity
    {
        return new TRepository();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do I register this generic repository as scoped and how do I do that in the Startup? I usually do something like services.AddScoped<MatchRepository, IMatchRepository>(); What do I do in this case?